# Sort vector by multiple values

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

i have to sort a vector. The vector contains pointers to objects of class "student".

the rating metric looks like this:

1. best finalgrade
2. if same finalgrade, less attempts
3. if same attempts, less id
4. students with 0 attempts are worse than students with 2 attempts and finalgrade 5, sort students with 0 attempts by less id

student looks like this:

```
private:
std::string name_;
int id_;
int attempts_;  //max 2, if 0, exam not taken
int grade1_;
int grade2_;
int finalGrade_;  // grade 5 for failed exam but still better than 0 attempts in rating
```

my problem is that i dont know how to handle attempts. because best number of attempts is 1 and its better than 2 attempts. but 2 attempts are better than 0 in the rating.

i hope you understand my problem and can help me. thx :)

Comment: you need a different kind of container, and it's likely to be a multimap or something where you have a key and a value.

Comment: @user2485710: That's not true, `sort` can take a comparison function that's arbitrarily complex.

Comment: @BenVoigt I don't think that `sort` will work out that well with multiple fields, probably you want a stable sort . Anyway I think that a vector is the wrong data structure for this.

Comment: @user2485710: The rules appear to prevent ever having a tie (ties are broken by ID, which is presumably unique), so stability of the sort is of no consequence.

Comment: @BenVoigt who said that you are sorting by `ID` ? Anyway this will be much simpler to manage with some SQL or other kind of data structure, that's my idea.

Comment: @user2485710: The question said it.  Notice that ties end up in sort level 3 and 4, where they are broken by ID.

Answer (score 9):

There is a function available in the STL, called [`std::sort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) Which can take a comparator function, (either a function pointer, or a function object).

The comparator function has to return a boolean that says whether the first element should appear strictly before the second element.

Here's what I came up with for the comparator:

```
struct compare_student {
    inline bool 
    operator() (Student *left, Student *right) const
    {
        if(left->attempts_ == 0 && right->attempts_ == 0)
            return left->id_ < right->id_;
        else if(left->attempts_ == 0)
            return false;
        else if(right->attempts_ == 0)
            return true;

        return 
            left->finalGrade_ <  right->finalGrade_ ||    // Compare final grade
            left->finalGrade_ == right->finalGrade_ && (  // If final grade same:
                left->attempts_ <  right->attempts_ ||    // Compare attempts
                left->attempts_ == right->attempts_ && (  // If attempts same:
                    left->id_ < right->id_                // Compare id's
                )
            );
    }
};
```

Obviously all your fields are private, so you will need to use their accessor methods rather than just accessing them directly, but here's how you use it:

```
vector<Student *> students {...};
std::sort(students.begin(), students.end(), compare_student{});
```

`std::sort` is not stable, this means if two elements are considered equal, then it is not necessarily the case that they will keep their relative order, which may be important to you. If it is, then there is *also* a function called [`std::stable_sort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/stable_sort/) which *does* have such a guarantee, and is used in exactly the same way:

```
std::stable_sort(students.begin(), students.end(), compare_students{});
```

**EDIT** *Notes on the implementation*

- `compare_students` is a class that has only one, public member, so rather than do this:

  ```
  class compare_student {
  public:
      ...
  };
  ```

  I shortened it to this:

  ```
  struct compare_student {
      ...
  };
  ```

  (the two are equivalent in C++, a struct is just a class with default public access.)
- Then as to what `inline bool operator()` means.

  - `inline` is a hint to the compiler that this function can be inlined, that is to say, replace the call with the code itself.
  - `bool` is the return type of the function.
  - `operator()` is the name of the function, It is a special-case function that gets called when you treat an object like a function:

    ```
    Student *a, *b;
    compare_student comparator {};

    comparator(a, b); // calls comparator::operator()(a, b)
    ```

Comment: thx, gonna try this when im at home.
just few questions.
do i need "struct" and what means "inline bool operator()" ?

when i wrote my sort funtions so far, i just wrote

bool sortSomething(Student *k, Student *j)
{...}

and then used this compare function as 3rd parameter in the stl::sort function

thx buddy

Comment: @d0zer: The comparison doesn't need to store any state, so a standalone function is perfectly fine and easier.  I also wouldn't use the huge `|| == &&` chain this answer shows.  But asQuirrel has given you a big clue.

Comment: @d0zer Depending on whether the comparator is used a lot, the function object facilitates inlining a bit better than a function pointer would. If this is not a concern, then yes, a function pointer is just as good. P.S. updated the answer with an explanation for the comment you left.

Comment: hey, was on business trip and had no time to check this. where have i to create that struct?

inside of my student class?

Comment: i implemented the sort as normal sort. not as function object because i didnt know, where to put that function object. it works.
only problem is, that students with 0 attemtps(worst metric) are shown first. then after those with 0 attempts the sort is correctly.

how can i put those with 0 attempts at the end?

Comment: @d0zer, switch the return true and return false that are related to 0 attempts.

Comment: Answer updated to reflect that change, thanks @BenVoigt

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the first line of your comparison function should be

```
if (left.attempts_ == 0)
```

From there, check whether `right.attempts_ == 0` as well.  If yes, check the IDs.

If no, then right has a grade and left doesn't, right is better.

Continue on with the rest of the rules.  Eventually you can use rules like `if (left.attempts_ < right.attempts_)` but only after you've dealt with 0 attempts.

Comment: i solved it with your and asQuirreL`s help. only problem is, that students with 0 attemtps(worst metric) are shown first. then after those with 0 attempts the sort is correctly. how can i put those with 0 attempts at the end?